# When can we assume that the wavefunction is separable

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

While working out the stationary states of a single particle in a 3d infinite potential box ($V=0$ inside a cuboid of known dimensions, $V=\infty$ everywhere else), I realized I had to assume the wavefunction was separable into a product of three functions, $\psi(x,y,z)=X(x)Y(y)Z(z)$, in order to find $\psi$. Why is this so, and under what conditions? What guarantees me that I can do this? The text I'm following isn't particularly clear on this.

Comment: There are actually good rigorous proofs of the fact that the assumption of separability for particular systems does not "destroy" any information about the problem, and I vaguely recall they involve examining the invariance of the Hamiltonian under the action of Lie groups associated with the symmetry group of the system, but I honestly don't know the specifics. Needless to say, most intro books avoid mention of such difficulties entirely (as otherwise the text would spiral down a complicated path that would be pedagogically suicidal).

Comment: I see. I was wondering if we could simply assume this to be true for nearly all practical applications, or if there were pathological counterexamples, or no counterexamples at all.

Comment: There are many counterexamples. For example, you could try to assume that the particle in 2D box has eigenstates which are separable in polar coordinates $(r,\phi)$, but this fails because the eigenstates turn out to be not separable in those coordinates. However, most prototypical exactly solvable quantum systems are modeled in a coordinate system in which the system winds up being separable, so when you learn about them, you don't have to worry about it. But in general, it is not necessarily safe to assume the system is separable in any arbitrary coordinate system.

Comment: A more complicated example of the general inability to separate variables is given by any situation in which the Born-Oppenheimer Approximation fails. For example, in molecular physics it is often assumed that there is a separability between the rotational, translational, vibrational, electronic, and nuclear-spin coordinates, but in reality this is an approximation that fails, for example, in the case of experimentally-observed spectral signatures of rovibronic coupling.

Comment: It is justified because it works. When you are solving a differential equation, the answer is uniquely determined by the equation and the boundary conditions. When you try a solution, if it works, then accept it. @DumpsterDoofus Your 2D box is square or a 2D sphere?

Comment: @luming: I was giving an example of a 2D square. You can formulate the Schrodinger equation for a 2D infinite square well in polar coordinates, assume separation of variables, and it will fail (because the wavefunctions are not separable in polar coordinates). The OP agrees that in the case of the 3D infinite square box, assuming separation of variables yields solutions which satisfy the Schrodinger equation. I assume what he is worried about is whether there are any eigenstates which are "missed" by applying this assumption.

Comment: That said, in the special case of the infinite 3D cube, you can rigorously prove that separation of variables must give all solutions, because the Hamiltonian is the direct sum of three operators, which (I think?) means that the wavefunctions are tensor-products of the eigenstates of the individual operators, which means that the eigenstates are Cartesian separable. For more complicated systems, I have no idea how that works (it's too complicated for me to understand).

Comment: Rod Vance or some of the other really high-rep users might know, though.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus In the case of infinite square box, I thought we can separate variable in $r$ and $\theta$, then satisfy the boundary condition of the square box. We should obtain the exactly same eigenvalues when doing in the Cartesian coordinate. Isn't it true?

Comment: @luming: No, that doesn't work at all. For example, the ground state $n_x=1,n_y=1$ of the 2D infinite square well box with $L_x=L_y=1$ is $2 \sin (\pi  x) \sin (\pi  y)$, which can not be written in the form $A(r)B(\theta)$. You can prove the impossibility by inserting $x\rightarrow r\cos(\theta),y\rightarrow r\sin(\theta)$ and then plotting the result for fixed $r$ and variable $\theta$. It will never be constant for any choice of $r>0$. Thus, separation of variables fails completely in that case, no matter how hard you try.

Comment: @luming: Additionally, the ground state is singly-degenerate, so there is no possibility that there exists a linear combination within the degenerate subspace which admits a decomposition of the form $A(r)B(\theta)$. Otherwise, for the multiply-degenerate excited states ($n_x>1$ or $n_y>1$), you know that the wavefunction must always satisfy the zero boundary condition at the edges, but combining that with an assumption that $\psi=A(r)B(\theta)$ means that the wavefunction must be zero for all $r>0.5$, which includes many of the points inside the box! This is a contradiction.

Comment: @luming: Actually, forget about my reasoning in the sentence "plotting the result for fixed $r$ and variable $\theta$...", that was wrong. The correct reasoning is that in polar coordinates the ground state is given by $\psi(r,\theta)=\sin (\pi  r \sin (\theta )) \sin (\pi  r \cos (\theta ))$. However, the ratio $\psi(r_1,\theta)/\psi(r_2,\theta)$ is not independent of $\theta$ whenever $r_1\neq r_2$. However, if it were separable, you would obtain $A(r_1)/A(r_2)$, which is constant. This is a contradiction.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus As you said before, the Hamiltonian is direct sum of two operators $p_x^2,p_y^2$. However, when writing in the polar coordinate, the Hamiltonian cannot write as the direct sum of two operator in which each of them only contains $r$ or $\theta$. I think this explains why we cannot separate the wave function into the form like $A(r)B(\theta)$. Recall how we solve hydrogen atom problem, we can only separate the wave function like this: $R(r)Y(\theta,\phi)$, because we can only write Hamiltonian like $O(r)+O'(\theta,\phi)$

Answer (score 6):

Sepration of variables is indeed a delicate topic in partial differential equations. As of today we don't (to the extend of my knowledge) have a complete theory on the conditions that make it possible. The usual posture is to have existence and uniqueness theorems for the solutions of a given PDE and using some ansatz from separation of variables, by finding a general solution, we should have the solution as luming commented.

As far as I know, for specific cases we do have rigorous justification on using separation of variables in given coordinates, which are related to the symmetry group acting on the PDE (as BumbsterDoofus said also in comments). A (somewhat old) book explaining this is Miller's "Symmetry and Separation of Variables" that you can find online here http://www.ima.umn.edu/~miller/separationofvariables.html. As it says in the preface we do know how to justify for some PDEs (specially lower dimensional ones) but we do not have complete theory for all the differential equations we would like to consider (for instance the tridimensional wave equation). I do not know of further developments beyond Miller's book, but I have looked for it and have not found decisive changes (but that could be due to my ignorance).

In any case, as long as you're considering bound states I do not think you should be worried about those things, the existence and uniqueness theorems coupled with you being able to provide a general solution should suffice (I'm always suspicious of scattering states becaude they are not square-integrable and could be more subtle). If you're not satisfied with this answer, I guess it would make a great question on math stackexchange to ask for the status of separation of variables, though I think the answer relates to the symmetry group of the PDE in question anyway, and could be overkill for your context.

Answer (score 5):

The logic goes like following.

We can guess solution in forms of $X(x) Y(y) Z(z)$ for a particle in 3-dimensional box. We can find such solutions. The question is, do we miss any solution?

The function $X(x)$ is eigenfunction of self-adjoint operator
$$H_x = -\frac{1}{2} \frac{ \partial^2}{\partial x^2} + V(x) \tag{1} $$
$V(x)$ is the potential of infinity wall. And the same for $y,z$. Thus they form a complete set of functions under suitable boundary condition. We expand the general form of solution as
$$ \psi(x,y,z) = \sum_{l} \sum_{m} \sum_{n} c_{lmn} X_l(x) Y_m(y) Z_n(z) \tag{2} $$

Since $[H_x,H]=0$, the eigenfunction of a particle in 3-dimensional box forms a simultaneous eigenstate as eigenfunction of $H_x$. We can drop $\sum_l$ and the $l$ dependence in the expansion coefficient $c_{clm}$ in Eq. (2). The same applies to $y$ and $z$. Therefore the eigenfunction of particle in three-dimensional box can be writen as $X(x) Y(y) Z(z)$ .